# Why am I getting a ClassCastException here?

Tags: java, android, preferences, classcastexception, preferenceactivity

I'm creating an android application and i'm trying to use a PreferenceActivity.

I'm getting the *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String* error when it gets to this line `return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(USER_TERM, USER_TERM_DEF);`

I thought it might be because I'm not converting it properly from it's string value in the EditText box to the int I need but I can't figure out how to fix this, or is that even the cause? I'm flummoxed.

Here's my preference activity class:

```
public class UserPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {
//option names and default vals
private static final String USER_TERM = "term_length";
private static final String USER_YEAR = "year_length";
private static final int USER_TERM_DEF = 12;
private static final int USER_YEAR_DEF = 34;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 
}

public static int getTermLength(Context context){
    try{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(USER_TERM, USER_TERM_DEF);
    }catch (ClassCastException e){Log.v("getTermLength", "error::: " + e); }
    //return 1;//temporary, needed to catch the error and couldn't without adding a return outside the block.//
}
public static int getYearLength(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(USER_YEAR, USER_YEAR_DEF);
}
```

And here's the bit of code where I'm trying to use the the preferences inside another class:

```
public float alterForFrequency(Context keypadContext, float enteredAmount, String spinnerPosition){

    int termLength = UserPrefs.getTermLength(keypadContext);
    int yearLength = UserPrefs.getYearLength(keypadContext);
}
```

The complete android logcat, i've uploaded here: http://freetexthost.com/v3t4ta3wbi

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace? What's the return time of `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`? What is the `getInt()` method's signature?

Comment: @Hunter2, Damn. Sorry i'm new to programming and shamefully can't answer any of those questions :/. But i can post the contents of androids logcat (which i have) if that helps, and if you'd be kind enough to tell me how to get a stacktrace in eclipse i'll do that too. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sure @Hunter2 meant the stacktrace of the `ClassCastException`. You could remove the try/catch and then post the logcat. Anyway it's `getInt(String,int)`, so that should be right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a preference that is stored as a `String` and you are trying to read it in as an `int`, hence the `ClassCastException`.

If you're happy to leave the preference stored as a string, you could just use `getString` and pass that value to `Integer.parseInt()` to get an `int`.

Otherwise, you need to make sure the value gets written to the preferences as an int.